# Unordered list as dict key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to be able to do something like:

```
foo = Counter(['bar', 'shoo', 'bar'])
tmp = {}
tmp[foo] = 5
```

In other words, is there a hashable equivalent for `Counter`?
Note that I can't use `frozenset` since I have repeated elements that I want to keep in the key.

**Edit:**
In my actual application, the objects in foo may not be comparable with each other so the list cannot be sorted.

Comment: Get rid of `Counter`, sort the list, convert to a tuple and use that as a key? (Devil's advocate to find the constraints to your implementation)

Comment: How long can the list be?  Is it something reasonable or are we talking thousands?  Any restrictions on the elements of the list?  One quick solution (if lists are short and can't have a certain special character in them) in them is to stringify the list.  For example `key = '|'.join(['bar', 'shoo', 'bar'])`.  You can always recreate the list later by splitting on the special character

Comment: Unfortunately, Python doesn't have a good solution for this.  I'd go with @roganjosh's solution above.  If there are going to be lots of duplicates, maybe make everything into tuples of (item count).  These, tuples, then, can be put into a frozenset.

Comment: @sedavidw don't forget to sort the list :)

Comment: What's wrong with `frozenset(foo.items())`?

Comment: @tzamanL Because repeated elements,

Comment: @martineau I just realized `frozenset(Counter([1,1,2]).items()) == frozenset(Counter([1,2]).items())` is `False`! dict_items seems to handle things as Tom's answer below explains.

Comment: @roganjosh I can have objects in the list that are not comparable so `foo` here may not be sortable unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you seem to require is a way to use unordered pairs of key-amount as keys. A `frozenset` is probably the way to go, although you will have to create it out of the `items` of the `Counter` and not its `keys`.

```
foo = Counter(['bar', 'shoo', 'bar'])
tmp = {}
tmp[frozenset(foo.items())] = 5

# tmp: {frozenset({('bar', 2), ('shoo', 1)}): 5}
```

If this is satisfying, you could implement this transformation by defining you own mapping type like so:

```
from collections import Counter

class CounterDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, Counter):
            self.data[frozenset(key.items())] = value
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, Counter):
            return self.data[frozenset(key.items())]
        else:
            raise TypeError

foo = Counter(['bar', 'shoo', 'bar'])
tmp = CounterDict()
tmp[foo] = 42
tmp[foo] # 42
```

You could make this implementation richer by making `CounterDict` a subclass of `collections.UserDict`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you could do.  One is to sort the list and convert the result to a `tuple`.  That will work fine for small lists.

If you have large lists (with duplicates), you could convert it into a `frozenset` whose elements are tuples which are (word, count) pairs.  So for the example, if your list is `['bar', 'shoo', 'bar']`, you would have `frozenset({('bar', 2), ('shoo', 1)})`.

You could construct this by using `Counter`, or else just construct a `dict` of `word: count` entries, then convert the entries to tuples and construct a `frozenset` from them.

Both of these would be hashable, and support duplicate elements in the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Using the string representation of the Counter?

```
foo = Counter(['bar', 'shoo', 'bar'])
tmp = {}

tmp[str(foo)] = 5
```

Comment: This was my first thought as well!  One problem with it is that the keys aren't sorted, so you can have logically-equivalent Counter objects with different string representations, but I think you could solve that by doing a little bit more massaging (say, `str(sorted(foo.items()))` to make it "stable").

Comment: @Samwise I think that wouldn't work if the objects in the list are not comparable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Counter` is a mutable object, and so is `dict`. If you are OK with converting it to an immutable one, then convert it to tuple. For example,

```
dict_as_tuple = tuple(sorted(foo.items()))
foo[dict_as_tuple] = 5
```

You can do backward conversion to dictionary by

```
d = {k: v for k, v in dict_as_tuple}
```

I agree with @roganjosh that it is a Devil's advocate advice, but that's the closest thing to a solution I may think of.

Comment: I'm _relatively confident_ that `foo.items()` from a `Counter` will now maintain order, and thus `items()` will unpack in a set order depending on the order of the strings it encounters. So, `['bar', 'shoo', 'bar']` and `['shoo', 'bar', 'bar']` will not be equal. You need to drop the `Counter` and sort the list to make it repeatable

Comment: Actually, I'm totally unsure on my own point now. Finally a question that makes me think :)

Comment: I think that if I covert the same Counter object generated in two different ways to tuples, the tuple object may be different. Thanks for the correction, I fixed the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Mapping keys need to be hashable.  We can create a HashableCounter subclass of Counter that provides a `__hash__()` method so instances can be used as keys.

Hash values must be equal if the objects are equal. The hash value must be independent of the order items are added to the HashableCounter.

The objects added to the HashableCounter are hashable.  Define a canonical order of the keys by sorting them by their hashes.  Then take a hash of a tuple of the ordered (key, value) pairs as the hash for the HashableCounter.

Caveats:

- If a HashableCounter is updated or changed, the hash value will
  change even though it's the same object (same HashableCounter
  instance).
- This may be seen as an abuse of the concept of a hash.
- A hash value may be different for different runs of the program,
  different Python versions or implementations, different OSes, etc.
- It's not an expected usage - document it.

Here's the code:

```
from collections import Counter

class HashableCounter(Counter):
    def __hash__(self):
        items = sorted(self.items(), key=lambda t:hash(t[0]))
        return hash(tuple(items))

foo1 = HashableCounter(['bar', 'shoo', 'bar'])
print(f"foo1 = {foo1}, hash = {hash(foo1)}")

# different order, same hash
foo2 = HashableCounter(['shoo', 'bar', 'bar'])  
print(f"foo2 = {foo2}, hash = {hash(foo2)}")

#use foo1 as a key
tmp = {}
tmp[foo1] = 5
print(f"tmp = {tmp}")

# update tmp using foo2 as the key
tmp[foo2] *= 3
print(f"tmp = {tmp}")

print(foo1 == foo2)
```

Output:

```
foo1 = HashableCounter({'bar': 2, 'shoo': 1}), hash = 8916343845449291478
foo2 = HashableCounter({'bar': 2, 'shoo': 1}), hash = 8916343845449291478
tmp = {HashableCounter({'bar': 2, 'shoo': 1}): 5}
tmp = {HashableCounter({'bar': 2, 'shoo': 1}): 15}
True
```